# Erratic Counter Code By VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I just wrote a VHDL code but it doesn’t work correctly. I want to write an erratic counter with D Flip-Flop that count like this: `0 –> 13 –> 5 –> 7 –> 12 –> 6 –> 3 –> 15 –> 10 -> 0`.
It should have these properties:

1. It should be structural
2. Four outputs (3 down to 0)
3. It should have an asynchronous reset
4. It should have an enable
5. It should have an active high clock.

I wrote my code below but I know it’s not OK. Can anyone help me please?

```
library IEEE ;      
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all ;         
-- and_gate 
entity and_gate is                  
  port(Input1, Input2:in bit;
  Output:out bit);
end and_gate;
architecture behavioral of and_gate is
  begin
    Output <= (Input1 and Input2) ;
end behavioral;
-- or_gate 
entity or_gate is                   
  port(Input1, Input2:in bit;
  Output:out bit);
end or_gate;                                                         
architecture behavioral of or_gate is
  begin
  Output <= (Input1 or Input2);
end behavioral;
-- not_gate 
entity not_gate is                   
  port(Input : in bit; Output : out bit);   
end not_gate;
architecture behavioral of not_gate is      
begin
  Output <= not(Input);
end behavioral;
-- D-FF
entity DFF is 
    port(CLK,RESET,EN,DIN :in bit;
    COUNT  :out bit);    
    end DFF;
architecture behavioral of DFF is 
begin  
    LSEQ :process(RESET,CLK) 
    begin 
        if(RESET ='0')then
            COUNT  <='0'; 
        elsif(CLK'event and CLK ='1')then
            if(EN ='1')then
                COUNT  <=DIN;
        end if;  
    end if;
 end process;
end behavioral;
-- counter 
entity counter is 
    port (CLK,RESET,EN: in bit;
         COUNT : out bit_vector(3 downto 0)); 
end counter;

architecture counter_structural of counter is 

component and_gate                                 
    port(Input1,Input2 : in bit; Output: out bit);
end component;

component or_gate                                  
    port(Input1,Input2 : in bit; Output : out bit);
end component;

component not_gate                                 
    port(Input : in bit; Output : out bit);
end component;

component DFF  
    port(CLK,RESET,EN,DIN :in bit; COUNT  :out bit);     
end component;

signal A,B,C,D,ai,bi,ci,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15 : bit;                          

begin 
    Gate1: not_gate port map (A,ai);                  
    Gate2: not_gate port map (B,bi);
    Gate3: and_gate port map (ai,bi,a1);
    Gate4: and_gate port map (C,D,a2);  
    Gate5: or_gate  port map (a1,a2,a3);    
    Gate6: DFF port map (CLK,RESET,EN,a3,COUNT(0));
    Gate7: and_gate port map (ai,B,a4);
    Gate8: not_gate port map (c,ci);                  
    Gate9: and_gate port map (ai,D,a5);
    Gate10: or_gate port map (a4,ci,a6);
    Gate11: or_gate port map (a5,a6,a7);
    Gate12: DFF port map (CLK,RESET,EN,a7,COUNT(1)); 
    Gate13: and_gate port map (A,B,a8);               
    Gate14: and_gate port map (C,D,a9);
    Gate15: or_gate port map (a8,a9,a10);
    Gate16: DFF port map (CLK,RESET,EN,a10,COUNT(2));   
    Gate17: and_gate  port map (ai,B,a11);
    Gate18: and_gate  port map (ci,D,a12);
    Gate19: and_gate  port map (ai,D,a13);
    Gate20: or_gate port map (a11,a12,a14);
    Gate21: or_gate port map (a13,a14,a15);
    Gate22: DFF port map (CLK,RESET,EN,a15,COUNT(3));   
end counter_structural ;
```

Comment: Part of a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is Complete - all information necessary to reproduce the problem and Verifiable - "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. What is is not doing correctly? (What is it doing?) Do you have a test bench? Is the count order provided required?

Comment: Please include a schematic diagram of this structure. Based on this code, it just looks like a bunch of connected gates to me.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use LFSR (linear feedback shift register). 
If you choose the correct parameters and correct first value, you get a pseudo random generator. 
The good point is that the correct parameters and first value are provided on web. (Google should provide it to you fast enough)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ring counter. A ring counter is just n registers with their inputs and outputs chained in a ring. The output of the final register can also be used as the output of the counter. The values that you want to output can be used as the register's initial and reset values. Make sure that the register's initial values are the reverse of what you want to output because the ring counter will output the initial value on register n, then n-1, n-2, etc.

In this case you can use:

```
register value
0        0
1        10  
2        15
3        3
4        6
5        12
6        7
7        5
8        13
9        0
```

Edit: Another benefit of using the ring counter is reuse of components. A structural ring counter only needs one component, a register. This will stop your code from being bloated by all of the component declarations like it is now.